# Upright [...] in italics quotation

Tags: csquotes, ellipsis

I've configured `csquotes` to show quotations in italics, but I want the output of `\textelp` to be in `\textnormal` shape. How can I accomplish this?

I thought it would be easy to just wrap `\textelp` but it produces a spurious `[]` that I can't account for.

[image: example]

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{csquotes}
\DeclareQuoteStyle[meide]{danish}
  {\itshape\quotedblbase}
  {\textquotedblleft}
  [0.05em]
  {\normalfont\guillemotright}
  {\guillemotleft}
\setquotestyle[meide]{danish}

\newcommand\ellision{%
    \textnormal\textelp{}%
}

\begin{document}

\enquote{abc abc abc \textelp{} abc abc abc} % the [...] is in italics

\enquote{abc abc abc \ellision{} abc abc abc} % the [...] is followed by empty brackets

\enquote{abc abc abc {\textnormal\textelp{}} abc abc abc} % same

\end{document}
```

Comment: You can also use `\let=` to save the previous definition of `\textelp`, then `\renewcommand\textelp`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`\textnormal` takes an argument, so you should write

```
\textnormal{\textelp{}}
```

instead.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{csquotes}
\DeclareQuoteStyle[meide]{danish}
  {\itshape\quotedblbase}
  {\textquotedblleft}
  [0.05em]
  {\normalfont\guillemotright}
  {\guillemotleft}
\setquotestyle[meide]{danish}

\newcommand\ellision{%
    \textnormal{\textelp{}}%
}

\begin{document}

\enquote{abc abc abc \textelp{} abc abc abc} % the [...] is in italics

\enquote{abc abc abc \ellision{} abc abc abc} % the [...] is followed by empty brackets

\enquote{abc abc abc {\textnormal{\textelp{}}} abc abc abc} % same


\end{document}
```

Comment: Doh! Thanks... :)